# Dynamic url for $http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

Here is what i try to do :
Json from "urldatas":

```
[{ "name" : "John" }]
```

JS file:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        this.getDatas = function () {
            var datas = $http.get('urldatas', {cache: false});
            return $q.all({datas});
        };
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http, $timeout) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.loadData = function () {
            var promise = service.getDatas();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
                console.log($scope.datas);
            });
        };
    vm.loadPackages = function () {
            var url = "urlPackages" + datas.name;
            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            $scope.MyPackages = response.data;
        });
};
```

So i try to dynamicly change url in $http.get in getPackages, by values from getDatas, but i don't know how to do it. url in console shows "urlPackagesundefinded". Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: As the service is written it will create compile errors. The question refers to `getPackages` but there is no such function in the code.  **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.** If your question isn’t about a compiler error, ensure that there are no compile-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

`$q` send multiple requests as an array, not as an object.  remove the curly bracket and add a square bracket

```
var datas = $http.get('urldatas', {cache: false});
return $q.all([datas]);
```

since you reference the `controllerAs` remove the scope variables and reference them through `vm`.

also in `then` promises response data comes under `data` property

```
var promise = service.getDatas();
promise.then(function (response) {
   vm.datas = response.data.datas.data;
   console.log(vm.datas);
});
```

Comment: I think there may also be a scoping issue to be dealt with.

Comment: @Raphael Rafatpanah yeah you were right  just edited it

Comment: Using `$q.all()` is an anti-pattern when `$http` already returns a promise